# Play online video streams from m3u8 file using libvlc, subitems is always 0

Tags: java, android, libvlc

I am trying to play media content using libvlc library. I have managed to play local files and IPTV broadcasts with the UDP protocol. Now I need to play TV channels that have open broadcasts over the internet.

I have found the same steps to follow in various StackOverflow answers. This is what I am trying to do:

1. Create a Media with m3u8 file URL.
2. Call parse on the Media, with the ParseNetwork option.
3. Explore subitems.
4. Play one of those subitems.

I'm using latest version of libvlc:

```
implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.3.4'
```

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private static final String TAG = "VLC TEST";

    private static final boolean USE_TEXTURE_VIEW = false;
    private static final boolean ENABLE_SUBTITLES = false;

    private VLCVideoLayout mVideoLayout = null;

    private LibVLC mLibVLC = null;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
        args.add("-vvv");
        mLibVLC = new LibVLC(this, args);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);

        mVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.video_layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        mMediaPlayer.attachViews(mVideoLayout, null, ENABLE_SUBTITLES, USE_TEXTURE_VIEW);
        this.setOnlineM3u8("https://ztnr.rtve.es/ztnr/1688877.m3u8");
        mMediaPlayer.play();
    }

    private void setOnlineM3u8(String urlString)
    {
        final Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse(urlString));

        boolean parseResult = media.parse(IMedia.Parse.ParseNetwork);
        if (parseResult)
        {
            MediaList subItems = media.subItems();
            if (subItems != null && subItems.getCount() > 0)
                mMediaPlayer.setMedia(subItems.getMediaAt(0));
            else
                Log.i(TAG, "No sub items");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Parse failed, state: " + media.getState());
        }
        media.release();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `subItems.getCount()` is always 0. I can play https://ztnr.rtve.es/ztnr/1688877.m3u8 file using oficial VLC for android app in the same testing device, so I think that I'm missing something. Do you know what is happening?

**Edit:**

Libvlc logs:

```
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/3b6c6974] libvlc libvlc: VLC media player - 3.0.11.1 Vetinari
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/3b726572] libvlc libvlc: Copyright © 1996-2020 the VideoLAN team
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/d0015] libvlc libvlc: revision 3.0.11.1-100-g9cb3252caa
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/d0015] libvlc libvlc: configured with ../configure  '--host=arm-linux-androideabi' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux' '--with-contrib=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi' '--prefix=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/install/' '--with-pic' '--disable-nls' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-avformat' '--enable-swscale' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-opus' '--enable-opensles' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-shared' '--disable-update-check' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-dbus' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-v4l2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-libva' '--disable-dv1394' '--enable-mod' '--disable-sid' '--disable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--disable-mad' '--enable-mpg123' '--disable-dca' '--disable-sdl-image' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--enable-fluidlite' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse' '--dis
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/ecd9c698] libvlc libvlc: plug-ins loaded: 368 modules
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [eb2a1e10/2d6e6f2d] libvlc logger: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [eb2a1e10/692d6e6f] libvlc logger: using logger module "android_logger"
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/1dd0] libvlc libvlc: translation test: code is "C"
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [eb2a1f90/1dd0] libvlc keystore: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 3 candidates
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [eb2a1f90/1dd0] libvlc keystore: using keystore module "memory"
2022-01-25 08:57:20.417 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f3b7c6b0/1dd0] libvlc libvlc: CPU has capabilities ARM_NEON FPU 
2022-01-25 08:57:20.421 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f4f7de70/1dd0] libvlc generic: creating audio output
2022-01-25 08:57:20.421 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f4eecd30/1dd0] libvlc audio output: looking for audio output module matching "android_audiotrack": 4 candidates
2022-01-25 08:57:20.422 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest E/VLC: [f4eecd30/1dd0] libvlc audio output: GetStaticFieldID(AudioFormat.ENCODING_IEC61937) failed
2022-01-25 08:57:20.422 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest E/VLC: [f4eecd30/1dd0] libvlc audio output: GetStaticFieldID(AudioFormat.ENCODING_DOLBY_TRUEHD) failed
2022-01-25 08:57:20.422 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f4eecd30/1dd0] libvlc audio output: using audio output module "android_audiotrack"
2022-01-25 08:57:20.423 7632-7632/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [f4f7de70/1dd0] libvlc generic: keeping audio output
2022-01-25 08:57:20.437 7632-7760/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef03d030/1e50] libvlc input: Creating an input for preparsing '1688877.m3u8'
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc meta fetcher: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/my.tests.vlctest/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/fetcher
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/my.tests.vlctest-1/lib/arm/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/fetcher
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc meta fetcher: no meta fetcher modules matched
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc art finder: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/my.tests.vlctest/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/art
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/my.tests.vlctest-1/lib/arm/vlc/lua/meta/art
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/art
2022-01-25 08:57:22.408 7632-7773/my.tests.vlctest D/VLC: [ef0232b0/1e5d] libvlc art finder: no art finder modules matched
```

Comment: share full libvlc verbose logs

Comment: Logs added to the question

Comment: try with the latest version https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/videolan/android/libvlc-all/3.4.8/

Comment: I get the same result and logs. The only change in logs is this line: ```libvlc libvlc: revision 3.0.11.1-172-gb4aad11d66```

Comment: I checked the paths of "Lua scripts" logs and they don't exist, could be this the problem?

Comment: try subscribing to the MediaList/media's itemAdded event. That parsing operation can take a while.

Comment: I tried ```media.setEventListener(this);``` before ```media.parse(IMedia.Parse.ParseNetwork);```, but in 5 minutes ```onEvent(IMedia.Event event)``` method is not called. Can ```media.parse()``` need more time than that?